# Laravel 5.5.40 file upload not working

Tags: php, html, laravel-5

I have downgrade laravel from 5.6 to 5.5.40 successfully.But now I have a problem : before downrading laravel input file was working, now it's not. When I write `$request->file('image')` it returns `null`.
I have set `enctype` but still is not working. The same form was working with laravel 5.6 ! Only input with `type="file"` is not working. Is there any one that can help me ?

view :

```
<form action="{{route('apply')}}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <input type="file" name="image"/>
    <br>
    </br >
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send"/>
</form >
```

in Controller :

```
public function apply(Request $request)
{
    return $request->all();
}
```

It returns:

```
{
    "_token":"o3s4YrXK2L98gU3H6JWFGSWbPfCdm7Z4JsM5azK3",
    "submit":"Send",
    "image":{}
}
```

Comment: can you share your code ?

Comment: please share a code

Comment: @CROZET ok,i have updated question now.

Comment: @Salman Zafar i updated question

Comment: @ArmandRexhmati are you selecting an image before submitting?

Comment: @Raymond yes,i'm selected it.

Comment: @crozet it returns true if i control with isvalid() .

Comment: Please check your route is of type post or any. It shouldn't be of type get

Comment: @Rob route is of type post.

Comment: @ArmandRexhmati try to return this return $request->image->getClientOriginalName();

Comment: What does `dd(\Request::file());` give you?

Comment: Or for that matter `dd($request->file());`

Comment: @Dimitri Mostrey thanks a lot man.I was messing with my self.This dd(\Request::file()); make me to understand what file retrun me.Thanks

Comment: Happy to help. If I'm not mistaken, L5.6 'merged' all send (requested) data into one method. Because you have downgraded, you had to take the 'older' way into account. Can I ask you, briefly, why did you downgrade? I love 5.6. This version has considerably made my site faster, in conjunction with PHP7.2

Comment: And i love version 5.6,but here where i work,server support max php 7.0,and laravel 5.6 require min php 7.1.3.So i downgrade laravel.But i love version 5.6.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Try This code to upload a file      

              public function apply(Request $request)
              {  
                           $file = $request->image;
                          //getting timestamp
                           $timestamp = time().str_random(20);
                           $name = $timestamp. '-' .$file
                            ->getClientOriginalName();
                           $file->move(public_path().'/images/', $name);

               }
```